# Is there anyway I can get all the locations inside a bounding box using google api?

Tags: google-places-api, openstreetmap, google-geocoding-api

I could not find anything which provides the functionality that I want online. The only thing I could think of so far is using the text_search with different location types (e.g. schools, parks, ...) I was wondering if there is an easier way for this. 
I also tried using the open street map but the locations that I get are mostly roads and residential areas names.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly possible. Generally speaking, the Google Maps APIs are not intended to be used as databases for obtaining exhaustive lists of anything.

The closest you can do is [Places API Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) with `rankby=distance` and different `type` values. This is limited to the nearest 60 results.